# Perl: Clear contents of file and open file in append mode

Tags: perl

I need to open a file in *append* mode in Perl, but I need that before opening file all the data is deleted and fresh data goes in.

I will be entering data line by line, so before entering the first line I need all previous data is deleted.

Please help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you are confused about what "append" means in perl. What you are describing is opening a file and truncating it, i.e.:

```
open my $fh, '>', $file;
```

This will delete the contents of `$file` and open a new file with the same name.

The reason to use open for appending is when you have a file that you do **not** wish to overwrite. I.e. the difference between `>` and `>>` is simply that the former truncates the existing file and begins writing at the start of the file, and the latter skips to the end of the existing file and starts writing there.

Documentation [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)

Answer (score 7):

[`truncate`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/truncate.html)

Comment: Actually it is much more easier to open the file in the right way. Why open it in append mode and then truncate it to 0 when it is easier to open it in write mode in the first place?

Comment: I don't know, I did not make up the crazy limitation. Also, today I was feeling in the mood to answer questions at face value.

Comment: opening by '>' is worse when we should do atomic operation using flock. Why? because we can't flock for closed file. Truncate is the best for that. We open file as '+<', flock, test and decide remove content or not.

Answer (score 2):

File handling includes:

1. Read a file (`<`)
2. Write in a file

   1. Append (`>>`)
   2. Overwrite (`>`)

For detailed explanation please visit [this](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/filehandling.html) link.

Answer (score 1):

`open(fileHandle, ">", $filePath);`